# Hovering over a div doesn't trigger overflow overlay scrollbar in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scrollbar, overlay

I have been using the overflow: overlay CSS property to display a scrollbar only when hovering over a  element in Chrome. This technique has been working fine until recently, but suddenly the overlay effect is no longer working. Instead, the normal scrollbar is displayed, taking up space and causing the content to shake when hovered over.

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue and if there have been any changes in the latest version of Chrome that might have removed support for overlay scrollbars. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="content">content</div>
<style>
  .content {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .content:hover {
    overflow: overlay;
  }
</style>
```

Note: I am using the latest version of Chrome.

Expected: When hovering over the  element, an overlay scrollbar should appear without affecting the layout of the content.

Actual: The overlay effect is not working, and the normal scrollbar is displayed, causing the content to shake when hovered over.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you create a runnable snippet because I'm unable to reproduce your problem (are you sure you're not seeing overflow on body rather than content?).

Comment: chrome update - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383750/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please give fix-width like given example.

```css
.content {
overflow: hidden;
width: 135px;
height: 100px;
scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges;
  }
  .content:hover {
   
   
overflow: overlay;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="content">content  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, voluptatem?</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. but I need for vertical scrollbar not horizoandal scrollbar

Comment: In your updated answer, The contents are shacking when hovering

Comment: Thanks, but in your answer the scrollbar is hidden because of that  `  ::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 1px;}`. but I need scrollbar with atleast 8px width so the user can use that scrollbar to scroll the content.

Comment: Now, You can check may updated answer with all solution.

Comment: Thanks @Prince, it works as per my need so accepting this answer. but it creates empty space for scrollbar on both sites of content. it would be good if the scrollbar present over the content without taking scrollbar space :)